# Why is this incorrect YAML syntax for a helm chart?

Tags: yaml, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

Based on the vanilla values [file](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml), I'm trying this YAML:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType
          operator: In
          values:
          - SPOT
```

...expecting it to work, but instead I'm getting *got "map", expected "array"* error.

The original values file has all but the first line commented out, and the first line is

```
affinity: {}
```

Doesn't this imply a map? Every example I have seen on the net uses my syntax, and yet it fails for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `affinity: {}` implies an empty map.

It would help if you tried converting it to JSON to understand what YAML is considering or not. I like to use [this tool](https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json).

Here is the output:

```json
{
  "affinity": {
    "nodeAffinity": {
      "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
        "nodeSelectorTerms": [
          {
            "matchExpressions": [
              {
                "key": "eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType",
                "operator": "In",
                "values": [
                  "SPOT"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't think the problem is in `affinity` but one of its children. Something there should be an array but is a map.